# Reliable sequential audio playback on Android

Tags: android, audio, media-player, playback, sequential

I am writing an android game for teaching kids to count. The instructions are read to the player through sound clips that are put together to form sentences (for instance "Place", "one", "cow", "in the", "barn". This requires a certain amount of reliability when it comes to latency so that the flow of the instructions sounds natural.

Currently I am using MediaPlayer, playing each sound in a OnCompletionListener. Each sound has it's own MediaPlayer that is created and prepared before playback of any sound starts (to reduce latency) - but still I get a significant delay before each sound the first time it is played (the second time it seems some sort of caching has taken place and it works fine).

The sounds are not many and very short and it should probably work better with SoundPool, but SoundPool has no way of knowing when an audio is complete and thus not an option.

Does anyone have any experience with similar problems and a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `handler` with `OnCompletionListener` and it worked fine for me to give delay between two sounds.

this way,

```
CommonMethod.player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                // /will use count and loop as per number of
                                // repetition chosen.
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    public void run() {
                                        if (counter >= limit) {
                                            CommonMethod.player.stop();
                                        } else {
                                            CommonMethod.player.start();
                                        }
                                        counter++;
                                    }
                                }, 3000);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: It's the other way around. I do NOT want delay between the sounds (or rather I want predictable delay. Your way ensures i have at leat 3 secs of delay, but player.start() it self adds to that delay making the playback sound unnatural)